# Basic CSS boiling my head

Tags: css

```
.long {
width: 100%;
}
.short {
width: 49.2%;
}
```

I have defined the above classes but for some reason when I reference 2 x short divs they are on separate lines (not side by side as expected).

This is the most basic of basic - I think the sun has got to me.

Comment: Did you mean to float them? Or inline-block?

Comment: Try setting their display to inline-block or floating them.

Comment: I have to run so I'm sure someone else will provide a comprehensive answer, but it's because they're block-level elements, which always appear on their own lines. You want `display: inline-block`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 3):

Div elements are, by default, `display: block`, `position: static` and `float: none` - so they cause line breaks, are in normal flow and don't let following content bubble up next to them.

You'll need to change one of those if you want them side-by-side.

`display: inline-block` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `<div>`s are block elements, not inline elements.

Try this:

```
.long {
    width: 100%;
}
.short {
    width: 49.2%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Divs are

```
display: block;
```

by default. If you change them to be

```
display: inline-block;
```

they should appear side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

Divs are block elements so they won't show up next to each other unless you add a float to one or both.  (Also, the .long class will make the div span the entirety of its container which would preclude any other elements showing up next to it.)

```
.long {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.short {
    float: left;
    width: 49.2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the attribute [float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp):

```
.short {
    float: left;
    width: 49.2%;
}
```

EXAMPLE

http://jsfiddle.net/7eS22/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block;` or float on your divs, like `float:left;`.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the "display" property as well.  The default for a div element is block, which accepts no elements next to it unless otherwise specified.

> display: block means that the element is displayed as a block, as
>   paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace
>   above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except
>   when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another
>   element, for instance).
>   http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

You can add:

```
.short { width: 49.2%; display: inline-block; }
```

Or you can float the first one:

```
.short:first-child { float: left; }
```

Either should essentially get you what you want.  There are additional things to note for either technique, such as overflows when floating or IE7 hacks for inline-block, but that gets you started at least.